# sql question about ordering after a sum

Tags: sql, plsql

i have a products table that contains all the sales as in quantity made at a time .. so the table is :

id | product_department_id | product_id | quantity_sold

i need to list for all the product_department_ids the best 2 selling products . Any ideas how i can do so ?

if you can do it in pl/sql it would be great but sql is ok also !

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
drop table quantity;

create table quantity (
  id number primary key,
  product_department_id number,
  product_id number,
  quantity_sold number,
  unique (product_department_id, product_id)
);

insert into quantity values (1, 1, 1, 10);
insert into quantity values (2, 1, 2, 20);
insert into quantity values (3, 1, 3, 30);

insert into quantity values (4, 2, 1, 60);
insert into quantity values (5, 2, 2, 50);
insert into quantity values (6, 2, 3, 40);


select * from (
 select quantity_sold, product_id, product_department_id,
       row_number() over (partition by product_department_id order by quantity_sold desc) r
  from quantity
) where r < 3;
```

*Edit* Still not sure about what exactly was asked, but if the combination prodcut/department can have multple entries then it would be:

```
drop table quantity;

create table quantity (
  id number primary key,
  product_department_id number,
  product_id number,
  quantity_sold number
);

insert into quantity values ( 1, 1, 1, 15);
insert into quantity values ( 2, 1, 1, 15);
insert into quantity values ( 3, 1, 1, 15);
insert into quantity values ( 4, 1, 2, 20);
insert into quantity values ( 5, 1, 3, 30);

insert into quantity values (10, 2, 1, 60);
insert into quantity values (11, 2, 2, 50);
insert into quantity values (12, 2, 3, 40);
insert into quantity values (13, 2, 3, 30);


select * from (
 select sum(quantity_sold), 
        product_id, product_department_id,
        row_number() over (partition by product_department_id 
                           order by sum(quantity_sold) desc
        ) r
  from  quantity
  group by product_department_id, product_id
) where r < 3
order by product_department_id, product_id;
```

Comment: Are you sure you can do an `order by sum(quantity_sold)` inside the analytical function?

Comment: If you partition by `product_id, product_department`, this will list the top 3 rows for every product-department combination.  That's probably the entire table?

Comment: +1 After rereading the question I think this answer is a better fit

Comment: @NamelessHorse: yes, you can *because* the analytical functions are evaluated after the aggergate functions/group by .

Answer (score 1):

If a product can have only one department, you can simply `order by`:

```
select  product_department_id
from    YourTable
where   rownum < 3
order by
        quantity_sold desc
```